# AJAX HTTP error 200, when try to update preview in views in drupal 7

Tags: php, ajax, drupal-7, view

I had drupal 7 installed and I had made some content types to dispaly data using views but it gives me AJAX HTTP error when I try to preview.

```
**Here is the error:**
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /timetrax_demo/?q=admin/structure/views/view/weekly_reports/preview/page/ajax
StatusText: OK
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/timetrax_demo\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven","theme_token":"l8sYxjGL6JL1HO62KPrEVLwqp1xOCJuJQP8HXX9jSYk","css":{"modules\/contextual\/contextual.css":1},"js":{"modules\/contextual\/contextual.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/js\/auto-submit.js":1}},"collapsiblock":{"blocks":{"block-views-client-user-listing-block":"2","block-views-users-listing-block-1":"4","block-views-closed-contract-block-2":"4","block-views-hired-user-block-1":"4","block-views-hire-user-block-2":"4","block-screenshot-update-software":"4"},"default_state":1,"slide_type":1,"slide_speed":200,"block_title":":header:first","block":"div.block","block_content":"div.content"},"better_exposed_filters":{"bef_datepicker":false},"viewsImplicitFormSubmission":{"views-ui-preview-form":{"defaultButton":"preview-submit"}},"ajax":{"preview-submit":{"wrapper":"views-preview-wrapper","event":"click","progress":{"type":"throbber"},"method":"replaceWith","url":"\/timetrax_demo\/?q=admin\/structure\/views\/view\/weekly_reports\/preview\/page\/ajax","submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"op","_triggering_element_value":"Update preview"}}},"clientsideValidation":{"general":{"months":{"January":1,"Jan":1,"February":2,"Feb":2,"March":3,"Mar":3,"April":4,"Apr":4,"May":5,"June":6,"Jun":6,"July":7,"Jul":7,"August":8,"Aug":8,"September":9,"Sep":9,"October":10,"Oct":10,"November":11,"Nov":11,"December":12,"Dec":12}}}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":"head","data":"\u003Cstyle type=\u0022text\/css\u0022 media=\u0022all\u0022\u003E@import url(\u0022https:\/\/cutyourpayroll.com\/timetrax_demo\/modules\/contextual\/contextual.css?nx859v\u0022);\u003C\/style\u003E\n","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":"head","data":"\u003Cscript type=\u0022text\/javascript\u0022 src=\u0022https:\/\/cutyourpayroll.com\/timetrax_demo\/modules\/contextual\/contextual.js?v=1.0\u0022\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E\n\u003Cscript type=\u0022text\/javascript\u0022 src=\u0022https:\/\/cutyourpayroll.com\/timetrax_demo\/sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/js\/auto-submit.js?nx859v\u0022\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E\n","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":null,"selector":null,"data":"\u003Cdiv id=\u0022views-preview-wrapper\u0022 class=\u0022views-admin clearfix\u0022\u003E\u003Cform class=\u0022clearfix\u0022 action=\u0022\/timetrax_demo\/?q=admin\/structure\/views\/view\/weekly_reports\/preview\/page\u0022 method=\u0022post\u0022 id=\u0022views-ui-preview-form\u0022 accept-charset=\u0022UTF-8\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-live-preview\u0022\u003E\n \u003Cinput type=\u0022checkbox\u0022 id=\u0022edit-displays-live-preview\u0022 name=\u0022live_preview\u0022 value=\u00221\u0022 checked=\u0022checked\u0022 class=\u0022form-checkbox\u0022 \/\u003E  \u003Clabel class=\u0022option\u0022 for=\u0022edit-displays-live-preview\u0022\u003EAuto preview \u003C\/label\u003E\n\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-textfield form-item-view-args\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Clabel for=\u0022preview-args\u0022\u003EPreview with contextual filters: \u003C\/label\u003E\n \u003Cinput type=\u0022text\u0022 id=\u0022preview-args\u0022 name=\u0022view_args\u0022 value=\u0022\u0022 size=\u002260\u0022 maxlength=\u0022128\u0022 class=\u0022form-text\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022description\u0022\u003ESeparate contextual filter values with a \u0022\/\u0022. For example, \u003Cem class=\u0022placeholder\u0022\u003E40\/12\/10\u003C\/em\u003E.\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv id=\u0022preview-submit-wrapper\u0022\u003E\u003Cinput class=\u0022arguments-preview ctools-auto-submit-click form-submit\u0022 type=\u0022submit\u0022 id=\u0022preview-submit\u0022 name=\u0022op\u0022 value=\u0022Update preview\u0022 \/\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cinput type=\u0022hidden\u0022 name=\u0022form_build_id\u0022 value=\u0022form-FT13LqXIqiSLgs3NQEYRqodve1BDQGqArrRG07lQYe4\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003Cinput type=\u0022hidden\u0022 name=\u0022form_token\u0022 value=\u0022GxklqCPy4JSZ88uH0M3jH9uhr3ESppeMTyEtKJDnmy8\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003Cinput type=\u0022hidden\u0022 name=\u0022form_id\u0022 value=\u0022views_ui_preview_form\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/form\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\u0022views-live-preview\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022view view-weekly-reports view-id-weekly_reports view-display-id-page view-dom-id-ade36c28d54fa186d566ccbd54b4f3f5\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022contextual-links-region\u0022\u003E\u003Ch1 class=\u0022section-title\u0022\u003ETitle\u003C\/h1\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022contextual-links-wrapper\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022contextual-links\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022title-edit first last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/timetrax_demo\/?q=admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/weekly_reports\/page\/title\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EEdit Title\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\n\u003C\/ul\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022preview-section\u0022\u003EUser Weekly Reports\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E      \n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022view-filters\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022contextual-links-region\u0022\u003E\u003Ch1 class=\u0022section-title\u0022\u003EExposed Filters\u003C\/h1\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022contextual-links-wrapper\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022contextual-links\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022exposed_form_options-edit first last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/timetrax_demo\/?q=admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/display\/weekly_reports\/page\/exposed_form_options\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EEdit Exposed Filters\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/li\u003E\n\u003C\/ul\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022preview-section\u0022\u003E\u003Cform class=\u0022ctools-auto-submit-full-form\u0022 action=\u0022\/timetrax_demo\/?q=admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/preview\/weekly_reports\/page\u0022 method=\u0022get\u0022 id=\u0022views-exposed-form-weekly-reports-page\u0022 accept-charset=\u0022UTF-8\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv\u003E  \u003Cinput type=\u0022hidden\u0022 name=\u0022q\u0022 value=\u0022admin\/structure\/views\/nojs\/preview\/weekly_reports\/page\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-exposed-form\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-exposed-widgets clearfix\u0022\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-field-user-name-uid-wrapper\u0022 class=\u0022views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-field_user_name_uid\u0022\u003E\n                  \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-field-user-name-uid\u0022\u003E\n            Select User          \u003C\/label\u003E\n                        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-widget\u0022\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-select form-item-field-user-name-uid\u0022\u003E\n \u003Cselect id=\u0022edit-field-user-name-uid\u0022 name=\u0022field_user_name_uid\u0022 class=\u0022form-select error\u0022\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002211564\u0022\u003Eabby.sanjuan\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00224688\u0022\u003EAdelaB\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00221776\u0022\u003Eaizlegaspi23\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002210845\u0022\u003EAjayT\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00222445\u0022\u003EAllanF\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002211345\u0022\u003EAmritpreetS\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00224684\u0022\u003EAngelA\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00223086\u0022\u003EAnneR\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022362\u0022\u003EAnnette\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022315\u0022\u003Eapolinar\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002212596\u0022\u003Easheesh\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00226397\u0022\u003EBerneR\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00222756\u0022\u003EBrianF\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00221859\u0022\u003ECamiA\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022455\u0022\u003ECathieB\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00222392\u0022\u003EChrisA\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022542\u0022\u003EChrisRose\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002212571\u0022\u003Edeepika\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002212566\u0022\u003Edemocontract\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00222755\u0022\u003EEdmarC\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00226394\u0022\u003EEdwardJ\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002210842\u0022\u003EFreyaB\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002211121\u0022\u003EGlendaUy\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00222464\u0022\u003EGraceA\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00227198\u0022\u003EHelbertC\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022498\u0022\u003EIramA\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022609\u0022\u003EJeanTan\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022220\u0022\u003EJessSilver\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022938\u0022\u003EJoanE\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00225587\u0022\u003EJodeR\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002210954\u0022\u003EJohnClacio\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00225274\u0022\u003EJohnN\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00224793\u0022\u003EJohnR\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00222462\u0022\u003EJoieA\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00229559\u0022\u003EJustinE\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022731\u0022\u003EKyleD\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00222891\u0022\u003ELadyA\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u002212594\u0022\u003Elakhbir\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00227214\u0022\u003EMaeV\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022364\u0022\u003EMaria\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u00226935\u0022\
```

1. Jquery update module is disabled.

Now Iam confused where is this error coming from.

Comment: >"Jquery update module is disabled" -- have you enabled it?

Comment: ye. after enabling it gives StatusText: Parseerror instead of StatusText: OK

Comment: and have you checked console for  parse error?

Comment: Yes I checked console too. But it is clear, no information there at console regarding parse error